# Вывод double числа

Tags: c#, числа, double

Рассчитываю pi
3.141592653589794 - это я вижу в отладчике
3.14159265358979  - это, когда вывожу 
Как мне вывести число полностью?

Comment: Вот код, который выводит _все_ десятичные знаки: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Советую ознакомиться с [вариантами форматирования вещественных чисел](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dwhawy9k.aspx?ppud=4). Для вашего случая подходит описатель формата `"R"`, который гарантирует идентичное число при обратном преобразовании (`double.Parse()`)

```
Console.WriteLine(pi.ToString("R"));
```